# Is there a standard solution in Java for concurrent value set exactly once?

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I need a structure allowing to set a value at most once concurrently.
Something that has methods similar to  `putIfAbsent` and `computeIfAbsent` of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

```
interface MyContainer<T>{
  void putIfAbsent(T value);

  void computeIfAbsent(Supplier<T> supp);

  Optional<T> maybeValue();
}    

// this implementation just shows intention
class DumbContainerImpl<T> implements MyContainer<T>{
  String key = "ONLYONE";
  ConcurrentHashMap map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, T>(1);
    
  void putIfAbsent(T value){
    map.putIfAbsent(key, value);
  }

  void computeIfAbsent(Supplier<T> supp){
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> supp.get());
  }

  Optional<T> maybeValue(){     
    return Optional.ofNullable(map.get(key))
  }
}
```

Is there something similar in a standard Java library? *(any JDK version)*

Comment: Not sure I understand the question well, do you mean something like AtomicReference, and if not, why not?

Comment: @NickL I read the question as something like AtomicReference initialized to null, but once assigned a non-null value, it becomes immutable ("set a value at most once").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) can be used, with its [`compareAndSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#compareAndSet-V-V-) method.

```java
class AtomicContainer<T> implements MyContainer<T> {
    private final AtomicReference<T> ref = new AtomicReference<>();

    @Override
    public boolean putIfAbsent(T value) {
        if (value == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        return this.ref.compareAndSet(null, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean computeIfAbsent(Supplier<T> supp) {
        if (this.ref.get() == null)
            return putIfAbsent(supp.get());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<T> maybeValue() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.ref.get());
    }

}
```

```java
interface MyContainer<T> {

    /**
     * @return true if the given value was assigned, false if a value was already assigned
     */
    boolean putIfAbsent(T value);

    /**
     * @return true if a value from the given supplier was assigned, false if a value was already assigned
     */
    boolean computeIfAbsent(Supplier<T> supp);

    Optional<T> maybeValue();

}
```